# What is the expected workflow without pull requests?

Tags: mercurial

I'm a big fan of Mercurial for my open-source projects, but I've never had the opportunity to use it at work.

I'm familiar with how Github pull requests work. **What is the expected workflow in the Mercurial world for collaboration, assuming that pull requests don't exist** (we don't use [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/31600#note_96793407))?

Say I have a public open-source repository, or a private work repository. How does someone propose non-trivial changes consisting of multiple commits? What options do we have for collaborating?

In the case of an open-source repository, I have to support both trusted and untrusted contribution requests. In the case of a work repository, I trust the contributor but the corporation mandate internal reviews for all contributions. Either way, it sounds as if we need a mechanism to notify authors of available contributions, some mechanism to discussion the contribution, and some mechanism to transfer changesets from the contributor to the official repository (given that the contributor might not have permission to push into the central repository but the central repository might have permission to pull from them).

Does code review software essentially handle everything I've mentioned above? Are pull requests really the only way to go?

Comment: It's been many years since I used Mercurial this way, but we used https://www.reviewboard.org/ (for whatever that's worth).

Comment: By "the corporation mandates a public review" did you mean an "internal" review?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Sorry yes. I've updated the question.

Comment: @torek Can you please post a formal answer clarifying your workflows? Also for what it's worth, I've run across https://www.phacility.com/ and it seems to have a nicer UI. Free if self-hosted.

Comment: Yes I think reviewboard is likely your option. A few years ago Steve Losh started an hg-review project. Unfortunately it hasn't been updated since 2016 and appears to be broken.

Comment: @Gili: since the last time I touched reviewboard was in 2015 at the latest, I don't remember any of the details.

Comment: @torek - latest RB doesn't work with latest HG. Sorry, I don't know details

Answer (score 1):

> What is the expected workflow without pull requests?

Push directly to the repository.

> Does code review software essentially handle everything I've mentioned
>   above?

**Yes**, you should try Phabricator. See for yourself if they use pull-requests (cross repositories push).

> Are pull requests really the only way to go?

**No**, but pull-requests fit well with most collaboration workflows. There are many ways. Pull requests favor pre-commit code-reviews, but you can also have a post-commit workflow.

If you are not using any code-review tool, only Mercurial and e-mails, you could do this:

- For trusted contributors, you can set a `fresh` branch (and/or repository) to receive commits, do post-commit code-review. If they pass review, merge with the `default` branch.
- For untrusted contributors, you can set a `contributor` repository to receive commits, do post-commit code-review. If they pass review, push it to the official repository, then merge with the `default` branch. Notify the review results using contributors e-mail (from the authors commit username).

If you find that only pull-requests fits your workflow or your tools, then the answer is: **Yes**.

Comment: Interesting idea. How would you prevent contributors from messing up the staging area, whether intentionally or not? In the pull-request scenario, one can only mess up their own repository. In your proposed scenario it's not clear what prevent one from stepping over other people's changes or even deleting history. Granted, this won't mess up the central repository but it'll prevent other contributors from sending commits.

Comment: A shared repository, this is a crazy idea, right? But sometimes, we want to do crazy things. Every repository is managed by the administrator, **you**. **Do not publish the repository as draft**, this would allow anyone to rewrite history. Overall, works like stackoverflow, you have to moderate the content. Strip garbage, remove spam. If they want to continue some other contributor commit, it's up to you to allow or prohibit (because this can be intentional, like a big experimental feature, that was almost accepted at some point in the past).

Comment: You could recommend(or demand) they always branch from the main branch. You can define if(or how) they should use bookmarks. You define allowed branches. Every time the official repository changes, you have to sync the contributor repo with the official repo. This a lot of manual labor, this is why people use specialized tools for this job.

Comment: Also, you can ask them to always create a new branch, that before you move to the official repo, the branch will be **rebased** to a single commit. So the official repo will not be polluted with temporary branches.

Comment: See how BitBucket allow you to have a wiki repository. You could do the same thing to manage code-reviews, issues. Like having a `code-review-report.txt` explaining why something was not accepted. If accepted telling what version/model/module should contain the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Public forks

- Ordinary and simple `hg pull` (each pull from fork will create at least anonymous branch, if not named)
- MQ with MQ-Collab extension

Private forks

- `hg bundle` + `hg unbundle`
- `hg export` + `hg import`

Any media and any type of works

- Exchange by shelves or queues

Comment: Okay, but how does a contributor notify the author of an available branch to pull? How do the two exchange review comments? The changeset transfer has always been easy. It's the collaboration (communication) part I don't get.

Comment: @Gili - by *any usable communication channel* is answer on both questions